# Questions about Python's recursive function course

Tags: python, recursion

I'm implementing an algorithm to find all combinations of m elements out of n.

I have verified the entire code through the answer, but because there are no comments, there are some parts that are difficult to understand, so I write a question.

For example, n = 7 for input, and 4 for to_pick, so `smallest = 0` because `len(picked) == 0` inside the function. Then, picked is returned if `smallest(0)` is inserted in the picked list in for statement and `to_pick == 0` through `pick(n, picked, to_pick-1)` again. ([0, 1, 2, 3])

But next I can not understand the process of picked being [0,1,2,4]. When `to_pick == 0`, the function is returned (is it returning an if statement instead of a function?) I wonder when `picked.pop()` will be executed.

If there is anything I am misunderstanding, kindly ask for guidance.

**Code**

```
def pick(n, picked, to_pick):
    if to_pick is 0:
        return print(picked)

    if len(picked) is 0:
        smallest = 0
    else:
        smallest = picked[-1] + 1

    for next in range(smallest, n):
        picked.append(next)
        pick(n, picked, to_pick - 1)
        picked.pop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = list()
    pick(7, result, 4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine this:

```
result = []
pick(7, result, 4)
```

What this code does is that at the first call it will set your smallest number to 0. So at this moment you have `smallest=0, n=7, to_pick=4`. From this moment you will have:

1- Your code goes into the loop, your empty list will append the smallest value.

2- After that the function will get called recursively, this time your to_picked value has decreased by one.

3- Your current smallest value will be the previous smallest + 1, and again you will go to the 2nd line.

4- After you hit the final condition, your list will get printed.The first time will be [0,1,2,3]. You will return out of the last recursive function, and will go to the next line.

5- This time the last item will get poped. so, your list will be [0,1,2].

6- You go a step further in the loop, this time your next value will be the smallest + 1, and your smallest value was 3. This will get appended, so your list will be [0,1,2,4].

Edit: so I have found out that your main issue here is that you cannot understand how return works in recursive functions. Imagine you have non-recursive functions like this:

```
def foo(A):
   return A
def bar(B):
   result = foo(B)
   return result
```

Here in function `bar` after function `foo` finishes its work, it will return to previous scope, which is the scope of function `bar`, and the next line will get executed, which is `return result`.

The logic is the same in recursive functions, the difference is that you are calling the same function over and over again. After you hit the final condition, you will return to the previous scope, until you hit the final condition again. And this action will get repeated to a point that you hit all possible final conditions.

So in your case, the first time you are hitting the final condition you will be having:

`n=7, picked = [0,1,2], smallest = 2, n = 1`

after you return from the final condition, your picked array will be `[0,1,2,3]` and the code will execute the next line. which will be `picked.pop()`. So you will end up with `picked = [0,1,2]` again, but this time your have reached the final line of the loop.

So the next time your `next` value will be updated by `smallest + 1` or `4`, and again this will get repeated until your loop has reached its end. and you will end up with `[0,1,2]` again.

After your loop's end, your function will return to the previous scope. This time `[0,1,2]` will get poped and you will end up with `[0,1]`, and the process repeats itself.

Comment: Return print (picked) is executed when [0,1,2,3] is returned. I already have a return, how can I tell if picked.pop () is executing?

Comment: @yosen. By looking at your outputs. When it returns, it goes to the previous function. Imagine if instead of a recursive function you were calling a simple function. After it returns, it will return to the previous scope and continues executing the code from the next line.

Comment: I was missing something small. Thank you!

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? Where does the next call come after [1,2,3,6] in the for loop? When n reaches 7, 6 is popped [1, 2, 3] and I wonder what happens.

Comment: @yosen your to_pick value is the number of values you want to pick from a given range. Here you want to pick 4 items from the list of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]. It's the combination of 4 out of 7, which will be 35 items. When your code hits to_pick == 0, it will return to its previous scope.

Comment: @yosen Check my answer now.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it right away and give you an answer.

Comment: OK. Let me try to understand your answer. May I have additional comments if you have any additional questions? I am deeply grateful for your help.

Comment: No problem, but if I have answered all your questions that are related to your title, don't forget to upvote or mark as the correct answer, so the next time someone sees this question looks at the answer that has helped you.

Comment: I followed your statement :) I return print (picked) after [0,1,2,6] is completed and picked.pop () is executed so picked is [0,1,2] I understood. In this case, since the smallest is 6 and the loop is 7, I can not loop any more. Can you tell me why picked.pop () is executed once more to become [0,1]? I have grown a little with your help, but I still do not know what I am understanding is the right answer. Sorry.

Comment: So you are in a scope that has a list of `[0,1,2]`, you have gone to all possible recursive options and there is no other way you can progress, your loop ends and you reach the end of the function, what happens? your function returns to its previous scope. What was the previous scope? the scope that had `[0,1]` and then called the function to add 2 in it, so after returning from it you will once again hit `picked.pop()`.

Comment: It is not clear that the function returns to the previous scope when it is finished. If I understand this, I think I understand everything. I will try to understand this. I saw the recursive function look similar to the push pop principle of the stack, is this correct? I think I should study more about recursion. If there is a basic algorithm that can learn recursion such as Fibonacci, please recommend it. Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: @yosen it's more about functions rather than recursive functions. If your function ends, it will return to the scope that it was called from. In recursive functions it gets a little more complicated since the same code gets called over and over again, but the logic is the same. You can look at this article. https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/